# Dividing data-frame columns and getting ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `dayData` which includes the columns the following columns `'ratio'` and `'first_power'` with the following types:

```
Name: ratio, dtype: float64 first power  
Name: first_power, dtype: object average power

  ratio   average_power
0     5            8.0
1     6            4.0
2     7            0.0
3     0            6.0
4     8            5.0
5     9            4.0
6     8            2.0
7     7            8.0
8     6            0.0
9     5            5.0
10    8            4.0
```

The next stage in my process is to create a second step power by dividing the 2 columns using the following formula:

```
dayData["second_step_power"] = np.where(dayData.average_power == 0.0, 0, dayData.first_power/dayData.average_power)
```

Obviously you can't divide by zero so in the event the average_power is zero I am trying to set the second_step_power to be 0, however I get the error:

```
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

What is the correct way of handling zeros?

My ideal output would be:

```
  ratio   average_power   second_step_power
0     5            8.0                0.625
1     6            4.0                1.500
2     7            0.0                0.000
3     0            6.0                0.000
4     8            5.0                1.600
5     9            4.0                2.250
6     8            2.0                4.000
7     7            8.0                0.875
8     6            0.0                0.000
9     5            5.0                1.000
10    8            4.0                2.000
```

Comment: Might be floating pt issue. Fix could be using : `np.isclose(dayData.average_power,0)`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried  dayData["second_step_power"] = np.where(np.isclose(dayData.average_power,0), 0, dayData.first_power/dayData.average_power) but got the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initially set all values to zero, then create a mask locating all rows with a valid denominator, i.e. where `power` is greater than zero (`gt(0)`).  Finally, use the mask together with `loc` to calculate `second_step_power`.

```
df['second_step_power'] = 0
mask = df.average_power.gt(0)
df.loc[mask, 'second_step_power'] = \
    df.loc[mask, 'first_power'] / df.loc[mask, 'average_power']
```